# Как правильно соединить провода USB и USB Type C?

Tags: железо, usb

Как соединить, или как это правильно назвать - спаять провода?

Получается, что у USB  идет всего 4 проводка:  **чёрный, жёлтый, белый и оранжевый**

У type С аж 7 шт: **зелёный, белый, жёлтый, 2шт розовые, 2шт серые**

Что с чем соединяется, какой цвет с каким?

Comment: Только через микросхему usb-хаба. А откуда вообще идея что тут можно обойтись паяльником?

Comment: @PavelMayorov зависит в общем-то от пожеланий, может быть и просто 5в человеку нужно, а может и QuickCharge и 480мбит.

Answer (score 3):

На вопрос о переходниках (`usb type c wiring pinout`), Интернет вещает вот такие гайды и картинки (обратите внимание на доп.резистор):

https://somanytech.com/micro-usb-c-wiring-diagram-connection-diagram-usb-c-assembly-diagram-design/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тут распиновка по разным типам USB:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]